# TurboGears 2 quickstart shows error immediately

Tags: python, pylons, turbogears2

I am new to TurboGears and have just installed TG2 development in a virtual environment. I'm following along in the [quickstart guide](http://turbogears.org/2.0/docs/main/QuickStart.html), and have successfully built a helloworld via

```
paster quickstart
```

I started the server and navigated a web-browser to localhost:8080

Wouldn't you know it, I immediately get an error, and not the welcome message the documentation suggests I should be seeing.

The error reads:

```
AttributeError: 'AcceptLanguage' object has no attribute 'best_matches'
```

Here's the trace:

```
URL: http://localhost:8080/
File 'C:\\VirtualEnv_1\\lib\\site-packages\\weberror-0.10.3-py2.7.egg\\weberror\\evalexception.py', line 431 in respond
  app_iter = self.application(environ, detect_start_response)
File 'C:\\VirtualEnv_1\\lib\\site-packages\\beaker-1.6-py2.7.egg\\beaker\\middleware.py', line 73 in __call__
  return self.app(environ, start_response)
File 'C:\\VirtualEnv_1\\lib\\site-packages\\beaker-1.6-py2.7.egg\\beaker\\middleware.py', line 155 in __call__
  return self.wrap_app(environ, session_start_response)
File 'C:\\VirtualEnv_1\\lib\\site-packages\\routes-1.12.3-py2.7.egg\\routes\\middleware.py', line 131 in __call__
  response = self.app(environ, start_response)
File 'C:\\VirtualEnv_1\\lib\\site-packages\\pylons-1.0-py2.7.egg\\pylons\\wsgiapp.py', line 107 in __call__
  response = self.dispatch(controller, environ, start_response)
File 'C:\\VirtualEnv_1\\lib\\site-packages\\pylons-1.0-py2.7.egg\\pylons\\wsgiapp.py', line 312 in dispatch
  return controller(environ, start_response)
File 'C:\\VirtualEnv_1\\Scripts\\HelloWorld\\helloworld\\lib\\base.py', line 27 in __call__
  return TGController.__call__(self, environ, start_response)
File 'C:\\VirtualEnv_1\\lib\\site-packages\\pylons-1.0-py2.7.egg\\pylons\\controllers\\core.py', line 211 in __call__
  response = self._dispatch_call()
File 'C:\\VirtualEnv_1\\lib\\site-packages\\pylons-1.0-py2.7.egg\\pylons\\controllers\\core.py', line 162 in _dispatch_call
  response = self._inspect_call(func)
File 'C:\\VirtualEnv_1\\lib\\site-packages\\pylons-1.0-py2.7.egg\\pylons\\controllers\\core.py', line 105 in _inspect_call
  result = self._perform_call(func, args)
File 'C:\\VirtualEnv_1\\lib\\site-packages\\turbogears2-2.1.3-py2.7.egg\\tg\\controllers\\dispatcher.py', line 230 in _perform_call
  setup_i18n()
File 'C:\\VirtualEnv_1\\lib\\site-packages\\turbogears2-2.1.3-py2.7.egg\\tg\\i18n.py', line 61 in setup_i18n
```

pylons.request.accept_language.best_matches()))
    AttributeError: 'AcceptLanguage' object has no attribute 'best_matches'

Did I mess something up when I installed it, or is this a problem with TurboGears?

Edit: I created a second project I named GoodnightMoon, this time without the Mako template option (which is the only difference between setups) and I get the same error:

```
'AcceptLanguage' object has no attribute 'best_matches'
```

Unfortunately this question is the only one I can find with a [web search](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&pwst=1&nfpr=1&sa=X&ei=W1GgTs-3J8LViALBwZFH&ved=0CBYQBSgA&q=%27Accept+Language%27+object+has+no+attribute+%27best_matches%27&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=b571422ac7922aeb&biw=1177&bih=760) related exactly to this error.

Are there any other clues I can use and provide to stackoverflow to assist in answering this question?

Following Michael Pederson's advice below, I researched the i18n. I have an i18n directory with only one sub-directory, named ru (Russian, I assume). I'm working on English-defaulted systems and browsers.

I'm using whatever the most current TG2 distro is at the time of this question, v. 2.1.3, and tg.devtools 2.1.x

Comment: This sounds like an issue with i18n, honestly. What is the default language in your browser? Which version of TurboGears are you using? Can you provide a link to the exact tutorial you are following? A couple of the older ones could be giving you bad instructions for the newest version of TG.

Comment: same for me here: any answer for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in wrong dependency to WebOb. IIRC 1.2b2 is installed which lack best_matches method on AcceptLanguage class. The easiest way to overcome that trouble is to replace WebOb-1.2b2 with stable WebOb-1.1.1.
This solution works fine for me.

PS: if you use virtual-env - just replace files inside lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob with ones from official site http://pypi.python.org/pypi/WebOb/1.1.1

Comment: thanks for the tip. my virtual env WebOb is in the form of an .egg - the one available online is not - how can I compile into an egg, or is that necessary?

Comment: Got it - cmd to the download directory while Virtual Environment is running, use easy_install setup.py install

Comment: That did it! That's the answer! I now get the welcome screen. :)

Comment: How did you know that was the issue?

Comment: just dug through the sources. From error it's obvious that class AcceptLanguage lack method best_matches, though there were several usages of it (pylons etc..). I looked through setup descriptors and found that webob requirement is something like >= 1.1. I decided to check that method against sources and found that it is present in 1.1.1. That's all

Comment: this solved the problem - thanks: for more clarification - you should go into the virtualenv - into lib\site-packages and there run: easy_install webob==1.1.1 that would install the right dependency

Comment: Ah, great tip. That saves a few steps.