# i18n breaking turbogears setup -wiki20 tutorial

Tags: python, pylons, turbogears2

ollowing the 20wiki tutorial as a Turbogears newbie

I'm using win7, python 2.7.2 (I guess the my computer locale is hebrew, but for the beginning I was planning on english development) and I think the turbogears version is 2.1.3

when I run the "paster serve --reload development.ini

I get in the localhost:8085 (I changed the default application port to
8085)
a server error page with the following message:
AttributeError: 'AcceptLanguage' object has no attribute 'best_matches'

I checked my i18n library and found there a sub folder with name ru , and only that subfolder (guess this stands for russian)

I tried to uncomment the lang= in development.ini and set it as lang =en or lang=en_EN  or lang = en_US or lang = en-US or lang = he but in all cases the error message just changed to:
LanguageError: IOError: [Errno 2] No translation file found for
domain: 'wiki20'
I also tried following the localization guide and setting 'he' language and translation files etc' followed the complete guide but - this didn't help at all

I found another person with the same problem in stackoverflow, but without an answer [TurboGears 2 quickstart shows error immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829653/turbogears-2-quickstart-shows-error-immediately)
the original traceback is here:
http://pylonshq.com/tracebacks/089af51be2370022eb0029ef6106168c

for the beginning I would actually prefer to disable all this i18n stuff .. but I can't find out how to do this

I'll be glad for any help with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this was answered here: [TurboGears 2 quickstart shows error immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829653/turbogears-2-quickstart-shows-error-immediately)

problem with webob - you should uninstall with easy install the current webob version (1.2b or something like that) and

```
easy_install webob==1.1.1
```

after that it'll work
I also got the following advice in the turbogears google group:
To be sture that you get the right things always install turbogears with:

```
easy_install -i http://www.turbogears.org/2.1/downloads/current/index tg.devtools
```